# Let $E^*=\{E⊆X \mid E=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} C_{I}$, $C_k=E_K-F_K , E_k,F_k∈\mathbb{E}$ for some $k∈\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{E}⊆\mathbb{P}(X)$ and $$E^*=\{E⊆X \mid E=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k C_I, \text{ where } C_k=E_K-F_K \text{ and } E_k,F_k∈\mathbb{E} \text{ for some } k\in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

i) If $\mathbb{E}$ is finite or numerable then $E^*$ is finite or numerable.

ii) If $\thinspace∅∈\mathbb{E}$ then $\mathbb{E}⊆E^*$.

iii) If  $\mathbb{E}$ is finite or numerable then the generated ring by  $\mathbb{E}$, $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{E})$,  is finite or numerable.

For (i) I consider, the two cases. If $\mathbb{E}$ is finite then $\mathbb{E}=\{E_1,E_2,\ldots, E_n\}$ then the different combinations of $E_k-E_j$ with $k,j∈\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are a finite set and also the unions.

If $\mathbb{E}$ is numerable the difference is numerable, and union of numerable is numerable.

For (ii) , $\thinspace C_k=E_k-E_k=∅∈\mathbb{E}$

For (iii) I would like to have your opinion. I'm not really sure if it's correct. And how could I do (iii)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid notational confusion, I am going to use $\Bbb E^*$ for your $E^*$.

You haven’t actually given an argument for (ii): you’ve simply shown that if $\Bbb E\ne\varnothing$, then $\varnothing\in\Bbb E^*$, which does nothing towards showing that if $\varnothing\in\Bbb E$, then $\Bbb E\subseteq\Bbb E^*$. You need to assume that $\varnothing\in\Bbb E$, let $E$ be an arbitrary member of $\Bbb E$, and show that $E\in\Bbb E^*$. In other words, you have to show that $E$ is the union of finitely many sets of the form $E_0\setminus E_1$, where $E_0,E_1\in\Bbb E$. This is very easy, and in fact you need only one set difference.

One way to prove (iii) is to start by letting $\Bbb E_0=\{\varnothing\}\cup\Bbb E$ and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ letting $\Bbb E_{n+1}=\Bbb E_n^*$. Then let $\widehat{\Bbb E}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb E_n$ and show that

- $\Bbb E\subseteq\widehat{\Bbb E}$,
- $\widehat{\Bbb E}$ is a ring, and
- $\widehat{\Bbb E}$ is countable (i.e., finite or countably infinite).

(You may find it helpful to show that $\Bbb E_0\subseteq\Bbb E_1\subseteq\Bbb E_2\subseteq\ldots\;$.) Clearly $\mathcal{R}(\Bbb E)\subseteq\widehat{\Bbb E}$, so $\mathcal{R}(\Bbb E)$ must be countable. (In fact $\widehat{\Bbb E}=\mathcal{R}(\Bbb E)$, but you don’t have to prove this.)

Answer (score 0):

For (i). To argue rigorously.

Let $\mathcal{C}=\{A\setminus B\mid A\in\mathbb{E}\mbox{ and }B\in\mathbb{E}\}$.
Firstly, we go to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is countable (i.e., finite
or countably infinite). Define a map $\phi:\mathbb{E}\times\mathbb{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$,
$\phi(A,B)=A\setminus B$. Clearly $\phi$ is surjective, so $|\mathcal{C}|\leq|\mathbb{E}\times\mathbb{E}|\leq\omega$
(i.e., the cardinality of $\mathcal{C}$ is less than or equal to
the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$).

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\mathcal{E}_{n}=\{\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\mid A_{k}\in\mathcal{C}\}$.
Define a map $\theta_{n}:\mathcal{C}^{n}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}_{n}$
by $\theta_{n}(A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{n})=\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}$. Again,
$\theta_{n}$ is surjective, so $|\mathcal{E}_{n}|\leq|\mathcal{C}^{n}|\leq\omega$.

Finally, observe that $E^{\ast}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{E}_{n}$,
so $E^{\ast}$ is countable (because a countable union of countable
sets is countable).